# Rails App Google Indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I noticed a problem with indexing my rails app when submitting it to Google webmaster tools and testing with curl.

My root is currently set like so:

```
map.root :controller => "posts"
```

which will explain when i run:

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

it only returns the posts controller and not the homepage in its entirety:

```
<div class="post" id="post_25">
<h2><a href="/posts/25">test</a><span class="date">09<br><b>Jul</b></span></h2>

<p><p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna.</p></p>

<h3 class="more"><a href="/posts/25">Read Post</a></h3>
<p class="comment_count">
    <a href="/posts/25">
        1 comment
    </a>    
</p>
```

Because of this I had to add my Google verification meta code into the posts view to get it to verify confirming my fears that when Google crawls my site all it is seeing is the posts controller.

How do I make it return the entire homepage and not just the post controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are somehow sending an RSS/Atom feed when the page is requested by certain user agents.  Check out the content type header in this verbose curl call:

```
$ curl -v http://alexefish.com/
* About to connect() to alexefish.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 174.129.212.2... connected
* Connected to alexefish.com (174.129.212.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.16.4 (i386-apple-darwin9.0) libcurl/7.16.4 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
> Host: alexefish.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/0.6.39
< Date: Mon, 12 Jul 2010 15:50:58 GMT
< Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "85c19351dbfb19431738e7b6f360025a"
< X-Runtime: 37ms
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Set-Cookie: _Blog_session=BAh7BiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7AA%3D%3D--fd6fef239709f99c7b2d7e2d353b22f1749fd3a1; path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 2442
< X-Varnish: 975219293
< Age: 0
< Via: 1.1 varnish
<
```

Perhaps you have some middleware or other application code doing this?

Comment: had a rengade bit of code that snuck into my controller:

respond_to do |format|
      format.atom
      format.html
end

didn't even notice it in there until now, 

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an application layout by creating `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. This will be used by all responses unless you specify otherwise. See this [Rails Guide on Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more details.

Comment: hmmm, this is what i am using for my layout, and alas it returns just the controller, i'll check out the guide